# Open iframe page in parent frame (javascript)

Tags: javascript, iframe, parent-child

I'm sure someone in the know has a solution to this problem I'm facing? I have a site with Index.html which contains an Iframe. In this iframe, all pages of the site are shown...Home.html..Info.html...Contact.html..etc.

I'd like a javascript function so that when you open Home.html via the google sitemap for example, it shows up in the parent frame in Index.html. The function I currently have in the head section of each child page is:

`<script>
    if (parent.location.href == self.location.href){
        window.location.href = 'index.html'
    }
</script>`

Although this works, it doesn't remember the child page and opens the Index page with the default iframe page...Home.html as the iframe is coded like this:

`<iframe id="iframe" src="home.html" allowTransparency="true" id="iframeID" name="iframeID" width="100" height="100" scrolling="no" frameborder="no">
</iframe>`

Has anybody a solution to this problem, as I've searched everywhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `location.href` with a query string, i.e.:

```
// .getAttribute so we don't get the absolute URL
var src = document.getElementById("iframe").getAttribute("src");
if (parent.location.href === self.location.href)
    location.href = "index.html?" + escape(src);
```

In index.html create a check for query strings and set the iframe source accordingly:

```
if (location.search)
    document.getElementById("iframe").src =
            unescape(location.search.substring(1));
```

Comment: @ MaxArt Thanks for your reply, I'm sure it's something along those lines, but being a "newbie" to javascript I can't seem to figure it out. My iframe ID is "iframeID", so that will presumably have to be changed in the code you gave me, but what else do I modify? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @RoadRunner Actually, *you* wrote `id="iframe"` in your post, I just used it... I can't know what else is to be fixed, since I don't know the rest of your page and code.

Comment: Correct, my apologies, it was written twice in the code by mistake. Still no luck I'm afraid..the entire site is online at euromodels.fr if that helps? Thanks