# Open iframe page in its parent when a direct link is to one of the child pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi I have multiple pages that reside in an iframe and I would like them to open in the parent page when say a search engine indexes them or people directly link to them.

Example: 
-this page will be the parent page and have an iframe 
-this will be first page.php
-then there will be second page.php, third page.php, fourth page.php, ect.

I would like it if someone linked to any of the pages that require the iframe to load the parent page with the iframe and load the url into that iframe.  So if someone links to say third page it will load the parent page and load third page in the iframe.

I have tried the following scripts that I have found from posts across the web but they only load the parent page with the original src in the frame.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>
    try { 
        if (top == self) {
            top.location.href = 'parent page.php'; 
        } 
    } catch(er) { } 
</SCRIPT>
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window == top) {
        var url = 'window.location.replace("parent page.php?var1=' + window.location.href + '")';
        eval(url);
    }
</script>
```

I also tried:

```
<body onload="refreshFrame();">
```

Then I saw the post on [Open iframe page in parent frame (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861653/open-iframe-page-in-parent-frame-javascript) here and it just brings up the page that was linked to and not the iframe.

The pages in the iframe are dymanically created as well so idk if that has anything to do with it or not.

But nothing seems to open the page inside of the iframe on my site it only loads the parent page with the original src first page in it.  So idk if this is possible with either javascript or php.

Also idk if anyone knows how this practice effects seo there are not many words and no  tags on the parent page so I was just curious about that too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try use the `base tag` in you iframe pages? Something like:

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

**UPDATE**

OK, so in your scenario you need to know if the current page is loaded on brownser or via iframe. And if it's not on iframe, redirect to your another page where you calling the iframe.

First thing first, check if the current page is inside a iframe with js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ( self === top ) {
        //Its not an Iframe;
    }
</script>
```

Now that we know if the page isn't load via iframe we can use a redirect inside that `if` statament:

```
window.top.location="http://www.yourdomain.com";
```

Now you need to make sure after redirect the page, the `iframe` `src` attribute will be the same url it was before. I'm assuming you can do that with a get parameter int the url? Let me know if find trouble in that part.

**UPDATE2**

Just add a get parameter in the url as i mentioned above. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ( self === top ) {
        //Its not an Iframe, needs redirect:
        var url = window.location;
        window.location="http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php?iframe="+url;
    }
</script>
```

Now in your index.php ( or whatever is the page that contain the iframe):

```
<?php
    $iframe_url = (isset($_GET['iframe']) && !empty($_GET['iframe'])) ? $_GET['iframe'] : "initial-url-content";
?>

<iframe src="<?=$iframe_url?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: i am trying to have it open with the parent attached if someone directly links to say second page or third page directly from an external site like if it were indexed in a search engine or something then it would pull up the parent page and load into the iframe.  Not links from within the iframe.

Comment: Let me see if i understood. What you want is if any people click on the url of `page3.php` file (assuming that should be a content of a iframe) be redirected to the main page with the iframe loading file `page3.php`?

Comment: Ya so if someone types in say page3.php into the address bar directly they will get the page 3 to pull up in the parent iframe page.

Comment: That is the problem that I am having.  As you can see I have the redirect code in the first and second example at the top but I can't figure out how to replace the iframe src with the correct url.  It will just redirect to the page and pull up the src that was originally stated on the page not the url that I was trying to access.

Comment: This works great thank you so much I have been messing with this for hours now I really appreciate it.