# Two different java scripts to do exactly the same thing?

Tags: javascript, iframe, hyperlink

I need to fix a problem with my website, and have come across two similar javascripts that are supposed to do the exact same thing to fix it:

1.

This HTML code should go in the head content area of the child pages:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> if(self==top) { top.location.href="/?url="+self.location.href; } </script>
```

and put this script block at the end of your BODY section after the close of the IFRAME:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> if (top.location.search.substr(0,5)=="?url=") { self.frames["ifrm"].location.href = top.location.search.substr(5); } </script>
```

2.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (self.location==top.location)
        top.location.replace(‘http://contain.er/page-url/here‘);
</script>
```

**What are the differences if any, and if there are differences, which one will work better in my case?**

For layout reasons I have top level navigation pages (Sections) which contain an iframe. The iframe is for sub navigation (topics), and the content pages are in a third iframe below it. Needless to say links to my topics and contents from other domains do not load in their parent frames, and the layout and navigation are broken. The scripts are supposed to fix it.

If you want to see for yourself: ["My site from the top"](http://www.rdelutherie.com)

You can "Enter" the site, and navigate to "Guitars" then to "New home planet", and all is well, but this does not work:

["Direct link to the New home planet page."](http://www.rdelutherie.com/rdelutherie/guitars/topics/newhomeplanet/newhomeplanet01.html)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The first one compares two "window" objects, `self` and `top`, to see if the current window *(`self`)* is the topmost *(`top`)* window, i.e. it checks that the window is not being framed.
It also uses `location.href` to redirect the browser if there is a match.

The second one does the same thing, but it compares the `window.location` object of the current window and the topmost window *(`self.location==top.location`)* instead of comparing the windows directly.
The second one uses `location.replace` to redirect.
The difference from `location.href` is in history only, `replace` does not add a history entry, it just replaces the current URL.

Functionally, they do the same thing, if the window is not loaded in an iframe, it's redirected to the given URL.
However, I have no idea how that is supposed to fix issues with your iFrames not loading.

Comment: I got the information from <a href="http://blog.futtta.be/2010/03/03/5-tips-to-tackle-the-problem-with-iframes/">here</a>.

The second point he makes.  The first one is the authors original code, and the second one is from a commenter (No explanation given to the difference).

I have no experience at all with java, and very little with web dev.  I do use Target=top in content pages, and in their parent pages I use target=parent, I am not sure why anymore, except for it works within my domain, it's people linking to pages on my site from other domains where it does not work.

Comment: Thanks adeneo, but I am none the wiser.

Comment: @BobZoid The link you posted is incomplete, but I can say that what you took from the site was explained incorrectly and the code itself is incorrect. My comments above explain what the scripts do and why.

Comment: I guess I need to ask a different question then.  Personally I don't care how my pages look on other peoples sites, they should make their own pages, not plagiarize mine, and I have no need of displaying content from other sites either.

Comment: I asked the question differently in a search, found this: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31597251/open-iframe-page-in-its-parent-when-a-direct-link-is-to-one-of-the-child-pages)  I can not make sense of it because the information is insufficient for me to implement it correctly.  I assume the Java script goes in between the head tags of the child page, he mentions a window.top.location="URL"; I have no idea what to do with or if it is even needed, where does the PHP script go, and how do I merge the Iframe tag with the one on my page without removing the default page? I can not ask no rep

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off (and I know you didn't ask), but your design screams of 1995 and is generally considered bad design. Today, we'd accomplish what you are doing with AJAX calls that return their results to a single container element that uses CSS to handle the text overflow (this replaces the various iframes) and the entire issue you are facing.

Now, to your question, both do the same thing, but the second one is more succinct in how it is expressing what it is doing. It is what has been come to have been called a "Frame-Busting" script that ensures that your site isn't loaded up inside of a frame in some other site. Although, I have to say that both scripts appear to be wrong in that they are comparing self and top for equality, when they should be checking for inequality.

Essentially "If the current window is NOT the same as the top window, then I must be displaying inside of some other window, which is not ok, so change the top most window's location back to my original site location.

I would change the == in both scripts to != to correct them.

See: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-framebuster or http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/jsFrames.htm for examples.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I don't understand any of it, and used a crowbar and much trial and error to make the site.  Both scripts are not being described as "Frame busters" to prevent other sights from displaying my contents, but as "redirects" to display my own pages correctly when linked to by search engines or from bookmarks...

Comment: Well after reading your reply I can see that you went straight for the script, but only skimmed over my question.  As for the site looking 95ish, you can thank Mozilla for taking artistic freedom on page display, and the people on SO for their help in making the site only 4 years ago!

Comment: @BobZoid I didn't skim over your question. Both scripts do the same thing. The differences between them are stylistic only. Indeed, both scripts do just what you said "redirects to display my own pages correctly", but they have nothing to do with search engine links or bookmark links. Again, these scripts do nothing in those cases. What these scripts do is make sure that if your page is ever attempted to be displayed in another site's frame, then your page will "bust" that frame and display correctly, hence the term "frame busting".

Comment: @BobZoid Also, the page looking 95ish has nothing to do with rendering by Mozilla. It is the design of the page. As I mentioned, if you want to accomplish a left navigation that causes the documents to load on the right and the two sides can scroll independent of each other, don't use frames at all, use AJAX calls and CSS to handle frame overflow.

Comment: @BobZoid Lastly, remember that right now, those scripts are actually incorrect. == should be !===

Comment: Scott, I used the iframes specifically to overcome gaps between the images because of firefox's handling of them, that caused the overflow, and a host of other issues (I know) I have meanwhile found some fixes, and am working on redoing the whole site without iframes, which will no doubt open up more cans of worms than I can deal with in a short time, so it may take a while!  The only Ajax I know is the stuff used to clean the sink after spilling the Java I drink!

If those scripts are indeed wrong, then I do not understand the many happy user comments!?!?

Comment: I'm just telling you like it is. I can't explain anyone else's "happy comments", but as someone who has been doing this for 20 years, I can tell you that if you try to compare the self window to see if it is equal to the top window and they are the same, then that means that your page NOT loaded inside of someone else's frame (a good thing and what you are trying to avoid). If that is the case, you would NOT redirect the user anywhere (as your scripts do). It is when self does NOT EQUAL top, that you would want to do that. Please refer to the links I provided for details.

Comment: You have already pointed out that those scripts will not do what I am trying to do, so my understanding them is mute, I have no need for frame busters!  I just needed a solution to my problem, but no one seems to get the point, and I have meanwhile found a solution.

Sometimes (Quite often) the solution is not in just answering the question, but in seeing where the question is leading to!

Comment: That's really an unfortunate response. Your question was "What are the differences if any, and if there are differences, which one will work better in my case?" and that question was answered. You then followed up with more questions, which we have addressed. In a forum like this, clearly stating your question is all the rest of us have to go on. We're not mind readers and when someone admits that they really don't have much knowledge about what it is they are asking (such as yourself), we don't have much to go on. Sorry, you didn't appreciate my answers.

Comment: adeneo answered my question, and pointed out that it will not fix my issue with the iframes not loading within their parents.  The key here is "My Issue", which I clearly stated, so you did have plenty to go by, and it had nothing to do with frame busting.  The scripts I asked about came with misleading info.  I thank you for your help, but it was not what I needed.  By asking more questions I hoped to find an answer to my problem, without having my inadequacies pointed out.  I am not a Web Developer, and not trying to be one, but I am a master of my craft and do have an engineering degree.